# Preventing browser from saving my geolocation angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function which get for me the geo location and the browser ask when i load the application to allow location.

When i refresh the browser the browser doesn't ask again to allow or not because the location is saved in the browser locations.

I want the browser NOT to save my location so every time i refresh the browser it ask's the user if it should allow to get geolocation or not.

is there a way to do that or it is not possible even.

```
function getUserLocation() {
      geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data) {
        vm.coords = {
          lat: data.coords.latitude,
          long: data.coords.longitude,
        };
        console.log(vm.coords);
      });
    }
```

i am using geolocation module.

[image]

Comment: That depends on the browser. Some will remember your selection, some will have a checkbox whether you want to have your selection remembered.

Comment: you can set the cache limit to 0.